# Testing database performance tools?

Tags: database, performance

What do you know the best tool to testing database performance? I'm looking for a tool which help me find weak performance places in my db during use application.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Which server?. DB perf in general or your app specific?.

Comment: I've had in mind MS SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two not obvious tools that can help you:

- [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) has support for [JDBC](http://www.soapui.org/JDBC/getting-started.html)
- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter) has a JDBC [sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) (don't miss these wonderful [plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/)!)

I said these tools are not obviouse because they are typically used for different targets (SOAP web services functional testing and HTTP accordingly). JMeter seems to be a bit better suited as it aimes for performance testing, but SoapUI can do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use SQL Server Profiler to capture a database-side trace, and then just sort by duration.

I do stuff like this 5 times a day.

Hope that helps

-Aaron MCITP: DBA

Answer (score 0):

You could use a source code level profiler to profile the application, which accesses your database. Profilers can identify the slowest lines of code. Most profilers can filter their results by namespace or special naming patterns, so could could filter out all non-database access code. You can then have a look which database queries are made on these slow lines.

In some database systems you can set up logging to log which queries where run and how long they took. Database monitoring applications can show you which queries are running at the moment, so you can identify the slowest/most often executed queries very easy. If this is no option you can log the queries you are doing in your app into a text file and then run them manually against the database, usually the time taken is displayed to the user.

A good feature to optimize database queries is the `EXPLAIN` command supported by many DBMS.

If you told us which database exactly you are running we could help more.

Comment: I'm running MS SQL Server (I used SQL Server Profiler and Tuning Advisor to analyze the performance), but Oracle interesting me too.